# integrate $\int \frac{1}{e^{x}+e^{ax}+e^{a^{2}x}} \, dx$

Tags: integration, special-functions

I've been trying to integrate 
$$
\int \frac{1}{e^{x}+e^{\omega x}+e^{\omega^{2}x}} \, dx 
$$
where $\omega=e^{2i\pi/3}$

but to no avail. I've tried substituting in $u=e^{(1+\omega)x}$ but ended up with an integral which looked like: $$
\int \frac{1}{u^{\frac{2+\omega}{1+\omega}}+u^{\frac{1+2\omega}{1+\omega}}+1}\,du
$$
multipled by some constant including $\omega$.
Does this integral have a closed form in terms of the hypergeometric function or otherwise?

**EDIT**

Let the integral be denoted by I then
$$
I=-\omega\int\frac{1}{u^{1-\omega}+u^{1-\omega^2}+1}\,dx=-\omega\int\frac{1}{u^{1-\omega}(1+u^{1+\omega})+1}\,dx
$$ using the notation from earlier.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{e^x +2e^{-x/2}\cos\frac{x\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$ does not look to have a nice primitive, but maybe the integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$ is more good-looking.

Comment: I just want to clarify, is $\omega$ itself supposed to be an exponential, or is it only the exponent? This is reminiscent of discrete fourier transform transfer functions.

Comment: $\omega$ is a constant (cube root of 1) that is multiplied by the $x$ in the exponential

Comment: what a monster...

Comment: Expanding the inverse of the denominator as a series or using binomial theorem implies we need na double sum, like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series).