# Proof of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\left (1- e^{\pi\sqrt3x}\cos(\pi x )\right )e^{-2\pi x/\sqrt3}}{x(1+x^3)(1+x^3/2^3)(1+x^3/3^3)\dots}~dx=0.$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, infinite-product

I have the following integral in my notebook:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\left (1- e^{\pi\sqrt3x}\cos(\pi x )\right )e^{-2\pi x/\sqrt3}}{x\prod_{j=1}^\infty (1+ x^3/j^3)}\ \mathsf dx=0.$$
Though after going through all my bookmarks, I can't find where I got it from, and I certainly do not know where to begin evaluating this integral. WolframAlpha offers no useful simplification of the integrand. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** ArXiv link to the original paper found! Here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07456.

Comment: I tried to substitute $x\sqrt[3]{1}$ into $x$ then redisue thm but apparently is not working

Comment: Potentially one could also use the Weierstrass product of gamma function to write a closed form of the denominator but then it turns into a quadruple integral which I don't think is the way to go..

Comment: @Nemo Apologies! I’ve added the link to your paper now that it’s been found and have bookmarked it so that this does not happen again :) Hopefully someone will read it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This integral is proved here https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07456 .