# Show this $\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln(2\sinh t)}{\left(3t^2+\ln^2(2\sinh t)\right)^2}~dt=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, closed-form

While evaluating the integral
$$
I_1=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sin\pi x~dx}{x\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^3}{k^3}\right)},\tag{1}
$$
I came to this integral of elementary function
$$
I_2=\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\left(i t\sqrt{3}+\ln(2\sinh t)\right)^2}.\tag{2}
$$
In fact $I_2$ is real and
$$
I_1=-2\pi I_2.
$$
These formulas imply the closed form
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t\ln\left(\,2\sinh\left(\,t\,\right)\,\right)}{\left[\,3t^{2} + \ln^{2}\left(\,2\sinh\left(\,t\,\right)\,\right)\right]^{\,2}}\,{d}t = 0,\tag{3}
$$
or alternatively
$$
\text{Im}\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\left(i t\sqrt{3}+\ln(2\sinh t)\right)^2}=0.
$$

Brief outline of proof is as follows. Write the infinite product in terms of Gamma functions, apply reflection formula for Gamma function to get rid of $\sin\pi x$, then use integral representation for Beta function and change the order of integration. Then one can integrate over $x$ to obtain the desired formula.
It seems that this should have a simple proof, but I don't see it.

> Q: Can anybody provide a direct proof ?.

Such a direct proof may shed light on possible routes to calculation or simplification of $(2)$.

Here is a numerical demonstration using Mathematica that the integral under consideration is $0$ up to at least $100$ digits:
[image]

The integrand for $t>w$ has been replaced by $\frac{1}{16t^2}$, resulting in the term $\frac{1}{16w}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio it was simple curiosity. I think this is enough reason to consider an integral.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio if you know how to apply residue theorem to directly prove this I will accept the answer, provided it is correct.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I do not remember making such a claim. Is it so hard to read carefully what other people are saying? Maybe it is when you have such an inflated ego.

Comment: [Be Nice.](/help/be-nice)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030017/proof-int-infty-infty-fracdx-leftexe-xeix-sqrt3-right2?rq=1

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio so you think one can come up with all these formulas without doing any work at all? "I have reasons for believing this particular user claims to be able to do what he is not (to apply the residue theorem, for instance), and he is just trying to exploit CASs and MSE users just for composing a post on his blog." - I haven't heard anything more stupid than this for a long time. You made me laugh hard, thanks.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I might dissappoint you, but I have proofs of every single formula posted in that question and posted on my blog. Maybe it is not a rigorous proof, but only formal one, I don't care. How can I exploit MSE for my blog I don't understand, because not a single question on these topics have been answered yet. Also if you look carefully (which you do not do) I always provide an original source of a formula posted on my blog. If there is not any source, than this means that I looked but din't find any.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio "Show me how you can turn the integral". I'm not your pupil at the high school that you are teaching at.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a great knowledge of WA or any CASs for that matter. I admire people who can use CAS to discover new formulas. So far I only have been using it for numerical check.

Comment: Now I understand when people are saying what a hostile place MSE is becoming for asking questions...

Comment: By numerical computation one can expect that $\int_0^1 \frac{t\ln(2\sinh t)}{\left(3t^2+\ln^2(2\sinh t)\right)^2}~dt=-\int_1^\infty \frac{t\ln(2\sinh t)}{\left(3t^2+\ln^2(2\sinh t)\right)^2}~dt$

Comment: @FDP, this is a great hint (and a very surprising result, in my opinion). I don't see any obvious change of variable trick here, because $\sinh \frac{1}{t}$ can't be expressed in terms of $\sinh t$ in a direct way. Very curious

Comment: @Yuriy: unfortunateIy i don't have a proof for this for now.

Comment: It seems that,  
$\displaystyle \int_0^{\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} \frac{t\ln(2\sinh t)}{\left(3t^2+\ln^2(2\sinh t)\right)^2}~dt=-\int_{\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^\infty \frac{t\ln(2\sinh t)}{\left(3t^2+\ln^2(2\sinh t)\right)^2}~dt$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer directly proves that:

$$\text{Im}\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\left(i t\sqrt{3}+\ln(2\sinh t)\right)^2}=0$$

First, we make a change of variable:

$$x=e^{-2t}$$

Which transforms the identity to:

$$\text{Im} \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x \left(\ln(1-x)-e^{\pi i/3} \ln x \right)^2}=0$$

Finding the imaginary part explicitly, we now need to prove:

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \ln(1-x)-\frac{1}{2} \ln^2 x}{x \left(\ln^2 x+\ln^2(1-x)-\ln x \ln (1-x)\right)^2}dx=0$$

---

Let's introduce a function:

> $$f(x)=f(1-x)=\ln^2 x+\ln^2(1-x)-\ln x \ln (1-x)$$

As we have a difference of two positive definite functions under the integral, the identity is equivalent to:

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \ln(1-x)}{x f(x)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{ \ln^2 x}{x f(x)^2}dx$$

Let's denote the integrals $J_1$ and $J_2$. We need to prove that $J_1=J_2$.

Using the substitution $x \to 1-x$ we can prove the following identities:

$$J_1=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \ln(1-x)}{(1-x) f(x)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \ln(1-x)}{x (1-x) f(x)^2}dx$$

$$J_2=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{ \ln^2 (1-x)}{(1-x) f(x)^2}dx=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{ (1-x)\ln^2 x+x\ln^2 (1-x)}{x(1-x) f(x)^2}dx$$

Subtracting the two forms of $J_2$ gives us another set of identities:

$$J_3=\int_0^1 \frac{ \ln^2 x}{x (1-x)f(x)^2}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{ \ln^2 (1-x)}{x (1-x)f(x)^2}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{ \ln^2 x+\ln^2 (1-x)}{x f(x)^2}dx$$

---

From the above follows a relation:

$$J_3-J_1=\int_0^1 \frac{ 1}{x f(x)}dx$$

Now we use integration by parts with:

$$u(x)=\frac{ 1}{f(x)}, \qquad v(x)= \ln x$$

The limits for $u(x)v(x)$ at $0$ and $1$ are both equal to zero. After simplifications, we can write:

$$J_3-J_1=\int_0^1 \frac{(2-x) \ln^2 x-(1+x) \ln x \ln (1-x)}{x(1-x)f(x)^2}dx$$

Making a substitution $x \to 1-x$ and adding the two results, we obtain a symmetric form of the integral:

$$J_3-J_1=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{(2-x) \ln^2 x+(1+x) \ln^2 (1-x)-3 \ln x \ln (1-x)}{x(1-x)f(x)^2}dx$$

From the other identities above, it can be finally seen that:

> $$J_3-J_1=J_3+2J_2-3J_1$$

Or immediately:

$$J_1=J_2$$

The proof is finished.

---

Remark. This doesn't use the other identity shown by  FDP in the comments. To me it looks very difficult to prove.

Answer (score 0):

What is following is too lengthy for a comment.

Define $g(t)=\displaystyle \frac{t\ln(2\sinh t)}{\left(3t^2+\ln^2(2\sinh  t)\right)^2}$ on $[0;+\infty[$.

Observe that, for $\displaystyle t>\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}
{2}\right),g(t)>0$

and,
$\displaystyle t\leq\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}
{2}\right),g(t)\leq 0$

let, $\displaystyle \alpha=\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$

$\begin{align}\int_0^{\alpha} g(t)\,dt+\int_{\alpha}^{\infty} g(t)\,dt&=
\left(\int_0^{1}g(t)\,dt-\int_{\alpha}^1 g(t)\,dt\right)+\left(\int_1^{+\infty}g(t)\,dt+\int_{\alpha}^1 g(t)\,dt\right)\\
&=\int_0^{1} g(t)\,dt+\int_{1}^{\infty} g(t)\,dt
\end{align}$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}g(t)\,dt=0$ is equivalent to $\displaystyle \int_0^{1} g(t)\,dt=-\int_{1}^{\infty} g(t)\,dt$